# No instance of function template remove_if matches argument list

Tags: c++

I am trying to remove whitespaces from a string

```
line.erase(remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), isspace), line.end());
```

But Visual Studio 2010 (C++ Express) tells me

```
1   IntelliSense: no instance of function template "std::remove_if" matches the argument list   d:\parsertry\parsertry\calc.cpp 18
```

**[Full Source](http://pastie.org/5114486)**

Why is that? A simple piece of code

```
int main() {
    string line = "hello world   111    222";
    line.erase(remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), isspace), line.end());
    cout << line << endl;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Verifies the function works?

Funny thing is despite that, it runs giving correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't question Intellisense, sometimes it's better to just ignore it. The parser or the database got screwed up somehow, so it doesn't work correctly anymore. Usually, a restart will fix the problem.

If you really want to know if the code is ill-formed, well, just hit F7 to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your source code compiles without even a warning with Visual C++ 11.0 (the compiler that ships with Visual Studio 2012).

Intellisense uses its own rules and isn't always reliable.

That said, your use of `isspace` is **Undefined Behavior** for all character sets except original 7-bit ASCII. Which means the heavily upvoted answer that you took it from, is just balderdash (which should not surprise). You need to cast the argument to (the C library's) `isspace` to `unsigned char` to avoid negative values and UB.

**C99 §7.4/1** (from the N869 draft):

> The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for testing and mapping
>   characters.
>   In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be
>   representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the
>   argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

A simple way to wrap the C function is

```
bool isSpace( char const c )
{
    typedef unsigned char UChar;
    return !!::isspace( UChar( c ) );
}
```

Why the `typedef`?

1. It makes the code easier to adapt when 
   you already have such a `typedef`, which is not uncommon;
2. it makes the code more clear; and
3. it avoids a C syntax cast, thereby avoiding a false positive when searching for such via a regular expression or other pattern matching.

But, why the `!!` (double application of the negation operator)? Considering there’s an automatic *implicit conversion* from `int` to `bool`? And, if one absolutely feels that the conversion should be explicit, shouldn’t it be a `static_cast`, and not `!!`?

Well, the `!!`  avoids a silly-warning from the Visual C++ compiler,

> “warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)”

and a `static_cast` doesn’t stop that warning. It’s good practice to quench that warning, and since Visual C++ is the main C++ compiler on the most used system, namely Windows, better do this in all code meant to be portable.

Oh, OK, but, since the function must be wrapped anyway, then … why use the old  C libary `isspace` (single argument) function, when the `<locale>` header provides a far more more flexible C++ (two arguments) `isspace` function?

Well, first and foremost, the old C `isspace` function is the one used *in the question*, so that’s the one discussed in this answer. I have focused on discussing just how to not do this incorrectly, that is, how to avoid Undefined Behavior. Discussing *how to do it right* brings it to a whole different level.

But regarding the in-practice, the C++ level function of the same name can be considered to be broken, since with g++ compilers until recently (and perhaps even with g++ 4.7.2, i haven't checked lately) only the C locale mechanism worked, and the C++ level one didn't, in Windows. It may have been fixed since g++ now supports wide streams, I don’t know. Anyway, there C library `isspace` function, in addition to being in-practice more portable and generally working in Windows, is also *simpler* and, I believe, more *efficient* (although for efficiency one should always MEASURE if it is deemed important!).

Thanks to James Kanze for asking (essentially) the questions above, in the comments.

Comment: Sorry I am new to C/C++, what do you mean by the last sentence, about the `isspace`? How do I cast the argument? I am just passing a "function" into `remove_if()`?

Comment: So how do I cast the argument?

Comment: @JiewMeng: at the time you asked, you could just have read up on casting in your favorite textbook. as it is, now you can also check the example given in the answer. but for the future, i recommend trying to find things yourself: it will help prevent doing *other things* that are wrong but not obviously wrong on the surface.

Comment: @Alf Why the typedef in such a local context.  And why the `!!`: there is an implicit conversion of the return type of `isspace` to bool, and `isspace` _logically_ returns a boolean value; the fact that it is declared `int` is for historical reasons.   And for that matter, why use the old, more or less broken function, when `<locale>` provides us with more flexible tools.  (OK, `<locale>` is perhaps not the best designed part of the standard library.  But it is "standard".)

Comment: @JamesKanze: re all the questions, each of those questions should better be an SO question on its own. For in contrast to the Usenet group where you and I are moderators, SO actively *discourages* discussion (as explained by e.g. Jeff, sorry I don't have link). And so these comments fields are *designed* to be unsuitable for discussion. :-(

Comment: @JamesKanze: re "why the `typedef`", it (1) makes the code easier to adapt when u already have such a `typedef`, which is not uncommon, and (2) it makes the code more clear, and (3) it avoids a C syntax cast, thereby avoiding a false positive when searching for such via a regular expression or other pattern matching.

Comment: @JamesKanze: re "why the `!!`", it avoid a silly-warning from the Visual C++ compiler, "warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)". it is good practice to quench that warning, and since Visual C++ is the main C++ compiler and the most used system, better do this in all code meant to be portable.

Comment: @JamesKanze: re "why use the old, more or less broken function", this question has an invalid assumption that it's the C function that is broken. from a formal point of view, perhaps it is so, but from a practical point of view, it is the C++ level function of the same name, that is broken, since with g++ compilers until recently (and perhaps even with g++ 4.7.2, i haven't checked lately) only the C locale mechanism worked, and the C++ level one didn't, in Windows. It may have been fixed since g++ now supports wide streams, IDK. Anyway, there's also *simplicity* and *efficiency*.the OP chose.

Comment: @James: I'm amending the answer to incorporate the explanations above. Thanks for focusing these details! :-)

Comment: @Alf Concerning the `typedef`, in this particular case, I find it reduces the readability of the code.  The important issue is that it _is_ `unsigned char`, and not some arbitrary type.  (And I've never worked on a project where we've had such a `typedef`.)  With regards to the warning, wouldn't the better solution be to use a `#pragma` to turn it off, rather than adding unnecessary verbiage to the code?  (And with regards to "broken" functions: both the C and the C++ version are broken, since neither work with UTF-8.  But that's another issue.)

Answer (score 0):

What is `isspace`?  Depending on the includes headers and the compiler
you are using, it's likely that your code won't even compile.  (I don't
know about IntelliSense, but it's possible that it's looking at all of
the standard headers, and sees the ambiguity.)

There are two `isspace` functions in the standard, and one is a
template.  Passing a function template to a template argument of another
function template does not give the compiler nearly enough information
to be able to do template argument deduction: in order to resolve the
overload of `isspace`, it has to know the type expected by the 
`remove_if`, which it only knows *after* template argument deduction has
succeeded.  And to do template argument deduction on `remove_if`, it has
to know the types of the arguments, which means the type of `isspace`,
which it will only know once it has been able to resolve the overload on
it.

(I'm actually surprised that your little bit of code compiles: you
obviously include `<iostream>`, and typically, `<iostream>` will include
`<locale>`, which will bring in the function template `isspace`.)

Of course, the function template `isspace` must be called with two
arguments, so if it were ever chosen, the instantiation of `remove_if`
wouldn't compile (but the compiler does not try to instantiate
`remove_if` until it has chosen a function).  And the `isspace` in
`<ctype.h>` will result in undefined behavior if passed a `char`, so you
can't use it.  The usual solution is to create a set of predicate
objects for your tool box, and use them.  Something like the following
should work if you're only concerned with `char`:

```
template <std::ctype<char>::mask m>
class Is : public std::unary_function<char, bool>
{
    std::locale myLocale;  //  To ensure lifetime of following...
    std::ctype<char> const* myCType;
public:
    Is( std::locale const& loc = std::locale() )
        : myLocale( loc )
        , myCType( &std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >( myLocale ) )
    {
    }

    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return myCType->is( m, ch );
    }
};
typedef Is<std::ctype_base::space> IsSpace;
```

It's trivial to add the additional typedef's so you get the complete
set, and I've found it useful to add an `IsNot` template as well.  It's
simple, and it avoids *all* of the surrounding issues.