# remove_if throw error when trying to remove white space

Tags: c++

I am trying to delete white spaces from the string. but got throw an error.

Which parameter did my code do wrong.. thanks for looking

My main function

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string myText;
    myText = readText("file.txt");
    myText.erase(remove_if(myText.begin(), myText.end(), isspace), myText.end());
    cout << myText << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the error appear when I try compile.

```
encrypt.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
encrypt.cpp:70:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘remove_if(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
encrypt.cpp:70:70: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:1131:5: note: template<class _FIter, class _Predicate> _FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate)
```

Comment: Can you show your includes and any `using` directives/declarations?

Comment: @juanchopanza added my includes statement.

Comment: Ah, `using namespace std` strikes again...

Answer (score 3):

You got this error because there are two functions with name `isspace`.

1. Defined in `locale` header, *namespace std*:

   ```
   template<class charT>
   bool std::isspace(charT ch, const locale& loc);
   ```
2. Defined in `cctype` header, *global namespace*:

   ```
   int isspace( int ch );
   ```

So, if you want to use second function, you have two ways:

1. Do not use `using namespace std`. I prefer it.
2. Use `::` to call the function, defined in *global namespace*

   ```
   remove_if(myText.begin(), myText.end(), ::isspace)
   //                                      ^^
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are several detailed explanations in:

[No instance of function template remove_if matches argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069552/no-instance-of-function-template-remove-if-matches-argument-list)

As summary, isspace is ambigous to the compiler. I would rather command not using it.

The code below works in G++ 4.7.2

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool isSpace(const char& c)
{
    return !!::isspace(c);
}

int main()
{
    string text("aaa bbb ccc");
    text.erase(remove_if(text.begin(), text.end(), isSpace), text.end());
    cout << text << endl;
    return 0;
}
```